# Excel 2016 Conditional Formatting - Compare Table to array

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have a table and two arrays. One array calculates the min and the other array calculates the max. Calculations are done per row. This means the first cell of the min array calculates the min cell of the first row of the table, and so on.

I want to conditionally format the table according to the calculated values in the arrays. I want the min cells in the table to be green, and the max cells to be red.

Can I do this without having to create a rule for each cell in the table?

Comment: Could we get a screenshot or some representation of these tables/arrays?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to create a "Min table" and a "Max table" that are the same in dimensions to your current table with just 1's for if that cell is the min or max for its row and use 2 rules (one for min and one for max) to highlight the cells appropriately ("=F3" for cell B3), making sure not to lock the cell references with "$". That way you only have 2 formulas.

Alternatively you could just use Tableau.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first row of the table begins with C1:X1, you can highlight the entire table with C1  as the active cell and select the Conditional Formatting , "Use A Formula..." option and input this formula to highlight the MAX  value within that row : =C1=MAX($C1:$X1).

You will need another rule for MIN values to be highlighted. Again with the entire table selected and C1 as the active cell, Select "New Rule", "Use A Formula..." option as before and type in this formula : =C1=MIN($C1:$X1).
This can be done entirely within the Conditional Formatting tool itself.